# Question about a proof, monotone differentiation theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

I have some problems understanding some technical details in the proof of monotone differentiation theorem in Donald L. Cohns book on measure theory (Theorem 6.3.3).

> Let $F: R \rightarrow R$ be non-decreasing. Then $F$ is differentiable $\lambda$-almost everywhere

Note: $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

The proof in the book is the following. He is first assumes additionally that $F$ is right-continuous, vanishing at $-\infty$ and bounded. This gives him a Borel measure $\mu$ such that $F(x) = \mu((-\infty, x])$ and he proves earlier that the right-hand side is a function which differentiable almost everywhere.

In the next step he drops the assumption of right-continuity, and defines $G(x) = F(x+)$, where $$F(x+) = \lim_{y \rightarrow x, y > x} F(y).$$ Then $G$ satisfies the hypotheses made in previous paragraph, and so it is differentiable almost everywhere. If $$G(x-) = \lim_{y \rightarrow x, y < x} G(y)$$ then he claims that $F(x-) = G(x-)$ and this I've managed to prove. From this he gets that $F(x_0) = G(x_0)$ whenever $G$ is continuous at $x_0$ and then that $$\dfrac{G(x-) - G(x_0)}{x-x_0} \leq \dfrac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x-x_0} \leq \dfrac{G(x) - G(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ from which he concludes that if $G$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $F$ is also and the derivatives are equal. I assume that he takes limits and that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \dfrac{G(x-) - G(x_0)}{x-x_0} = G'(x_0)$$ is true, but I've had some problems showing this. Is this trivial? Always true? Do I need to use any of the assumptions given on $G$?

Comment: Since $F$ is non-decreasing, its discontinuous points are countable thus of zeros Lebesgue measure, which don't affect the "almost everywhere" conclusion

Comment: @LiuGang I'm sorry but I miss how this helps. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: Since discontinuous points are of zeros Lebesgue measure, $F(x+) = F(x)$ almost everywhere, or say $F(x+)$ is a right continuous version of $F(x)$. And if $F(x+)$ is differentiable almost everywhere, so is $F(x)$

Comment: "LiuGang Thanks. That is how I reasoned. But now for a rigorous proof the author sandwiches the difference quotients of $F$ between two other difference quotients, as in my post. I feel like $G(x-)$ could be different from $G(x)$ for a sequence of points $x \rightarrow x_0$ and make the left-most and right-most quotients give different results.

Comment: I don't think the sandwich is necessary, prove the result for $F(x+)$, thus it is also true for $F(x)$. It's also a rigorous proof

Comment: Hey @BartoszMalman I happen to have the same problem as you. Did you manage to solve it? If so, how? Thanks!